# What package contains implementation for IUserEmailStore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, two-factor-authentication

I am working on the project that implements two factor authentication using SMS in C#. I am trying to use the interface called `IUserEmailStore` in my controller - so my controller's constructor look like this:

```cs
public AccountsController(
    SignInManager<User> signInManager,
    UserManager<User> userManager,
    IUserStore<User> userStore,
    IUserEmailStore<User> emailStore,
    RepositoryContext context,
    IMapper mapper, 
    UrlEncoder urlEncoder,
    JwtHandler jwtHandler)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _userStore = userStore;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _emailStore = emailStore;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _urlEncoder = urlEncoder;
        _jwtHandler = jwtHandler;
        _context = context;
    }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserEmailStore`1[TwoFactorAuthenticationGoogleAuthenticatorAngular.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'TwoFactorAuthenticationGoogleAuthenticatorAngular.Controllers.AccountsController'. 
    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired) 
    at lambda_method10(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[]) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext) 
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
```

I included the following relevant packages - including `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` referred by the Microsoft documentation of the `IUserEmailStore<TUser>` interface.

[image]

I am running out of ideas. Can somebody help?

Comment: May I ask why you're using SMS for MFA instead of TOTP? [SMS is the **worst** way to do MFA](https://cybernews.com/security/why-you-should-stop-using-sms-for-two-factor-authentication/).

Comment: The error you're getting **is not about any missing packages/references** - it's saying you haven't configured your DI container correctly. Show us your `ConfigureServices` method.

Comment: Sorry I am using One Time Password sent in SMS to my user  - that's what I meant.

Comment: You neeed to remove your `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` package reference - it doesn't apply to ASP.NET Core, and VS is even showing you a warning icon over it too.

Comment: _"I am using One Time Password sent in SMS to my user"_ - That's still insecure

Comment: I have included my Program.cs in my original question.

Comment: I have removed `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` from the project. The error is still there.

Comment: If SMS is the worst way is there any example how to do it better?

Comment: Using TOTP via something like Google Authenticator. What version of ASP.NET Core are you using?

Comment: I am using .Net 7.0 as a target - was that your question?

Comment: It is. I see you have `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` referenced, but that package is deprecated (hence only being as new as version 2..2). You should reference version 7.x.x of `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core`.

Comment: I have removed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity` and added `Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core` - the exception is still thrown

Comment: @janci Tell us what `TwoFactorAuthenticationGoogleAuthenticatorAngular` is.

Comment: It's just a namespace - I am experimenting with the code so some names might be bit strange.

Comment: @ ProgrammingLlama @Dai Hi Gents, any other ideas. I am getting desperate.

Comment: @janci We can't really help you without having greater access to your project

Comment: I have solved the problem by finding how other projects tackled it. So basically I don't DI the `IUserEmailStore` into my controller. I DI instead a `IUserStore` and you cast it to `IUserEmailStore` - as Microsoft returns really `IUserEmailStore` (`IUserEmailStore` derives from `IUserStore`). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by finding how other projects tackled it. So basically I don't DI the `IUserEmailStore` into my controller. I DI instead a `IUserStore` and I cast it to `IUserEmailStore` - as Microsoft returns really `IUserEmailStore` (`IUserEmailStore` derives from `IUserStore`). That's it.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. You can mark it so that it can help more people